# Is there a Chinese translation of Tesniere's Elements of Syntactic Structure?

Tags: syntax, resource-request, dependency-grammar

Is there a Chinese version of Elements of Syntactic Structure written by Tesniere? Has anyone ever translated it into Chinese?

Comment: Here's a paper in Chinese discussing Tesnière's works: http://www.lingviko.net/tesniere.pdf (“Tesnière” is 泰尼埃 in Chinese). As far as I can see, this paper mentions neither the name of his book _Éléments de syntaxe structurale_ in Chinese nor any of its edition in China, which can be a sign there's no Chinese translation of that book. But that's just my own guess.

Comment: Thank you for the paper you provided.  It gives an account of the core idea of what Tesniere held about dependency syntax.

Comment: Based on that article, it appears the most common Chinese translation of the title is 结构句法基础, and apart from 泰尼埃, it seems also 特斯尼埃 and 特斯尼耶尔 are both used for his name.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think there is a Chinese translation of Tesnière's oeuvre. I recall a few years ago -- in about 2015 -- that there was someone who was planning to produce a Chinese translation, but I was skeptical that the effort would ever amount to much. The problem at the time was that the person was planning to translate from the English version to Chinese, and they had also not organized a native French speaker to collaborate on the project. Any such project should include two or more people, one of which should be a native speaker of French, so that the translation can occur from the French original.

Comment: Got it. A native speaker of French will help to authenticate the originality of the translation, rendering the work more accurate.

Comment: Yes, precisely.